# How to convert a drawn multipolygon to a list of polygon in google earth engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to know if this is possible to convert a multipolygon to a list of seperated polygons. because I drew several polygons as multipolygon in code editor and now i separate for training-testing procedure. any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there might be several options on the table. but if you want to handle that on the server side you can do it in this way:

```
// a function which converts a multipolygon to a list of polygons
var multipoly2polylist = function(multipoly){
    var size = multipoly.coordinates().size()
    var polylist = ee.List.sequence(0, size.add(-1), 1)
    var polylist = polylist.map(function(listelem){
        return ee.Geometry.Polygon(multipoly.coordinates().get(listelem))
    })
    return polylist
}
```

(if we suppose that you drew multipolygon named farm), then you can use this function for farm multipolygon object.

```
var farm_polylist = multipoly2polylist(farm)
```

I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Given a `ee.Geometry.MultiPolygon` called `geometry`, you can get a list of the separate `ee.Geometry.Polygon` items by calling:

```
var list_of_polygons = geometry.geometries();
```